# Timeouts are always 5s

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.4

I am trying to read the configuration file to retrieve "play.ws.timeout.request". In order to do this I have this line of code: `Integer timeout = Play.application().configuration().getInt("play.ws.timeout.request");`
In my application.conf, I have `play.ws.timeout.request = 25000`

My problem is that, it always returns 5000, regardless of what I have in the configuration file (as seen in the screenshot). I even added a new config param just to make sure that it reads the correct file.
[image]

Any idea on why or how to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There was another library that had a configuration file (included in my main conf) AFTER i declared my timeouts. And that configuration file overwriten the data.